# Changing Mac AppStore default installation location from Xcode 4

Tags: macos, app-store, xcode4

I have an application that I want to distribute through Apple's Mac AppStore. The application has to be placed at a specific location. I was testing Xcode 4 archiving process. But it only generates installer which installs at `/Applications` folder. I want it to be installed in a different folder. How do I specify the new path?

Another thing. After the installation the installer relocates the Application to other location if there is any previous installation. How do I disable this action?

Comment: I do not believe this is possible; Apple's software is an exception.  I believe that the Apple App Store Agreement states that you cannot change the installation point to another point.